# How to install ssl certification on odoo ubuntu

Tags: server, ssl, odoo

I have Odoo11 installed on ubuntu and I need to install SSL certification. any infrastructure

thanks in advance

Comment: The SSL certificate is usually installed on the webserver (Apache; NGINX etc).  If you know the details of your server, you may be able to use LetsEncrypt: https://letsencrypt.org.  If you have a custom certificate, you will need to manually install it on your Web Server.  There's a good tutorial here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/282529/how-can-i-configure-apache2-for-ssl-and-install-a-ssl-certificate

Comment: Also see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/deploy.html#https